# Query cannot be parse SELECT avg_galoon, avg_galoon

Tags: sql, oracle

I dont know if its the right way to multiply that way, I want to multiply the avg_galoon that is sold weekly  by the price of it which is 20

```
 SELECT avg_galoon,
        avg_galoon * 20 + NVL(total income , 0)
 FROM customer;
```

Comment: `total income` is having a space, variable names with space is not allowed

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You should store the price of 20 in the database. So if the price changes you can update it in one place

Comment: Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-00904: "TOTALINCOME": invalid identifier)

Comment: Seems like TOTALINCOME is not a column in the customer table. You can see the columns by either DESCRIBE customer; or SELECT * FROM customer; I would do the latter to get familiar with the data as well.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to answer it. What is avg_galoon? Is it a column in your table? Is it a value that should be calculated? What is "total income"? You're making us guess at what the problem is. Please consider editing the question to make it more clear what you have and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`total income` isn't a column name from the customer table.
If you disagree and can see that column name (via methods mentioned in the comments already) then you will need to enclose that column name in the appropriate syntax for the database engine you are using i.e. [total income] for Microsofts SQL Server, `total income` for MySQL etc.

In future avoid the use of spaces in column names.